# Rails 5: group datetime in hash of year, month, day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this query:

```
dates = MyModel.pluck("distinct date(datetime_column)")
Hash[dates.group_by(&:year).map{|y, items| [y, items.group_by{|d| d.month}]}]
```

which find distinct dates and then gives me this array:

```
=> {2017=>{12=>[Tue, 12 Dec 2017], 1=>[Sun, 01 Jan 2017]},
 2016=>{11=>[Sun, 20 Nov 2016], 12=>[Sat, 24 Dec 2016, Mon, 12 Dec 2016, Fri, 30 Dec 2016]}}
```

**How do I add 3rd level to have hash where there are particular days under each month?** Thank you for any help!

**Update**

If someone needs ordered result, try this for "dates" part:

`dates = MyModel.order(:datetime_column).distinct.pluck(:datetime_column)`

For better performance can try to use this:

```
dates = MyModel.order("date_trunc('day', datetime_column) DESC")
               .distinct.pluck("date_trunc('day', datetime_column)")
```

Here is nice [blog post on using datetrunc](https://alexpeattie.com/blog/grouping-activerecord-by-day-or-week-with-datetrunc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), but you need to initialize the object correctly. It's a Hash of Hashes of Hashes!

```
require 'date'
a = Date.today
b = Date.new(2017,1,3)
c = Date.new(2015,12,5)
d = Date.new(2015,11,7)

dates = [a,b,c,d]

hash = Hash.new { |h, y| h[y] = Hash.new { |h2, m| h2[m] = {} } }

dates_by_ymd = dates.each_with_object(hash) do |date, h|
  h[date.year][date.month][date.day] = date
end

require 'pp'
pp dates_by_ymd

# {2017=>
#   {1=>
#     {7=>#<Date: 2017-01-07 ((2457761j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
#      3=>#<Date: 2017-01-03 ((2457757j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}},
#  2015=>
#   {12=>{5=>#<Date: 2015-12-05 ((2457362j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>},
#    11=>{7=>#<Date: 2015-11-07 ((2457334j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>}}}
```

In your case, you'd write :

```
dates = MyModel.pluck("distinct date(datetime_column)")
hash = Hash.new { |h, y| h[y] = Hash.new { |h2, m| h2[m] = {} } }

dates_by_ymd = dates.each_with_object(hash) do |date, h|
  h[date.year][date.month][date.day] = date
end
```

Note that this code returns `Date` objects as leaves of the nested hash, as you mentioned in your question.

If you want a modified version of your code, you can use this Rails code :

```
dates.group_by(&:year).map do |y, items|
  [y, items.group_by(&:month).map { |m, days| [m, days.index_by(&:day)] }.to_h]
end.to_h
```

Comment: `distinct date(datetime_column)` - there are a Date objects(not Time)

Comment: @Ilya So ? Both objects answer to `year`, `month` and `day`. This way, I can check that my code works, and incidentally, that yours doesn't.

Comment: Thank you! What do you say about @Inpego suggested solution?

Comment: @Eric Duminil proposed solution works as well. Rails community rocks! :)

Comment: @matiss : Inpego's solution works, but doesn't return the same structure as in your question. The leaves of its nested Hash are days, mine are `Dates`, like in your question.

Comment: Yes, you are right as Inpego's solution returns this `=> {2017=>{12=>[12], 1=>[1]}, 2016=>{11=>[20], 12=>[24, 12, 30]}}`  however your solution returns `=> {2017=>{12=>{12=>Tue, 12 Dec 2017}, 1=>{1=>Sun, 01 Jan 2017}},
 2016=>{11=>{20=>Sun, 20 Nov 2016}, 12=>{24=>Sat, 24 Dec 2016, 12=>Mon, 12 Dec 2016, 30=>Fri, 30 Dec 2016}}}`

Comment: @matiss: BTW, there's no need to rush in accepting an answer.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, true - I have to be more carefull with that. One more question - do you have some idea how to get the hash to this [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)? My final goal is to have those dates in treeview.

Comment: This should probably be another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dates = MyModel.pluck("distinct date(datetime_column)")
dates.group_by(&:year).map do |y, items|
  [y, items.group_by(&:month).map { |m, days| [m, days.map(&:day)] }.to_h]
end.to_h
```